# How can I download maps from mapquest?

Tags: qgis, mapquest

I need to get a detailed map for my own purposes. I need it detailed as much as I can see the buildings (like google map hybrid mode). I went to http://open.mapquest.com/ but I couldn't find the way to download a map for Dubai city as example!
How can I do that?
I need the map data to apply a vector layer on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the map only to apply a vector layer on it, why didn't you use the OpenLayers Plugin?

[image]

Now, about the MapQuest: remember that map consists of a lot of 256 x 256 px tiles. As stated [here](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map) they currently offer two tilesets: the `MapQuest-OpenStreetMap Tiles` and the `MapQuest Open Aerial Tiles`. You can freely use only the `MapQuest Open Tiles` (under some conditions).

If you access the `Developer Tools` in your browser you'll easily identify your desired tiles:

[image]

After downloading the tiles you may recompose the desired map portion.

But I still think it is easier to use OpenLayers Plugin.

Comment: I tried it already, but it gave me the whole map of the world not a certain portion of it!

Comment: It seems there are some problems on your machine. QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour runs smoothly with this plugin.

Comment: Actually I didn't find `developer tools`..! I am in http://open.mapquest.com/maps?city=Dubai&country=AE and I didn't find how to activate the developer tool..

Comment: If you use Chrome: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/?hl=fr. Or simply press **Ctrl + Shift + I** on the desired page. Same in Opera (the newest versions) For Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/web-developer/ For Safari: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111216193307AAboS9Q In Internet Explorer >=8 just press F12

Answer (score 0):

Get [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/).

Load any web map layer, or an offline .osm file. From the menu, Map > set printing bounds; adjust it.

Zoom in to the level you want.

Click Tool > Export to Bitmap, or hit Ctrl+E